# Getting row identified by foreign key reference in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a music streaming app. There are multiple songs in the app. Each user may "save" a  song to their library.

So, the base model "song" has things like song_id,title,songduration,artist,album.

Then, there's a "usersong" model that has many rows. Each row is just a user_id and a  song_id. When a user logs in, I get a list of songs they've saved by querying their user_id to that table. But, I'd like to get the full "song" row referenced by song_id, without having to store information in both songs and usersongs, and without having to make a 1000 individual queries.

Here is the "song" migration (shortened for simplicity):

```
  Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id', 32);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->float('length');
})
```

Here is the "usersong" migration:

```
 Schema::create('usersongs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); // a koel reference
        $table->string('song_id', 32);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('song_id')->references('id')->on('songs')->onDelete('cascade'); 
        });
```

Here is the UserSong model, for the above schema. What's the best way to make the "getByUserId" function to return all "songs" belonging to the user with user_id, in a single query?

```
class UserSong extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];


    protected $table="usersongs";

    public function getByUserId($user_id){
        $this->where("user_id",$user_id)->get();
        /// how do I get the song rows automatically in this function?
    }
    protected $fillable=["user_id","song_id"];
}
```

Ideally I would call it in another script like:

```
$songs=UserSong::getByUserId($someuserid);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use scope and relationship:

**Example**

```
//scope
public function scopeGetByUserId($query, $someuserid)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $someuserid);
}

//relationship
public function userSongs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Song', 'song_id');
}
```

Use:

```
$songs = UserSong::getByUserId($someuserid)->with('userSongs')->get();
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes)

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [Relationship Existence Query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)?

In your **Song** model, you should define your relationship with **User**.

```php
class Song extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(UserSong::class);
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can write:

**MyAwesomeController**

```php
Song::whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($yourUserId) {
    $query->where('id', $yourUserId);
})->get();
```

There you'll get the Collection of the songs linked to your User.

---

By the way, your `UserSong` should maybe extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` instead of `Model`.

For further explanations, you can take a look at Laravel's [Many to Many Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score -1):

you can use this to to do joining in a easy and fast way

https://github.com/themsaid/laravel-model-transformer